# How do I get CasperJS to continuously run tests?

Tags: windows, batch-file, casperjs

I'm running CasperJS tests from a Windows batch file, and am trying to get the tests to automatically re-run when they've completed using a label and goto statement:

```
:loop
casperjs test tests/casper-tests.js --xunit=tests/log.xml
goto loop
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as casper detaches from the shell and doesn't return control to the batch file after executing. Is there any other way I can get the tests to automatically re-run?

Comment: Did you install CasperJS through NPM? If so, you should try installing CasperJS from git (either the same version or current master).

Comment: I did install with NPM. I'll give it a shot from the repo. Is there an issue with installing casper from NPM?

Comment: Yes, it's a strange combination of python scripts and batch files. Git contains an exe file that can be directly executed. Keep in mind to add the path to the new casperjs folder to the front of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: You could try with `start "" /WAIT "casperjs [...]"`...